# What was the story reason behind making Carnelion IV so far behind?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes

In the canon *Star Wars* comic, *Obi-Wan & Anakin*, the Jedi pair travel to the planet Carnelion IV, where a distress signal has been sounded. The planet is ravaged by war, with its most advanced technology being a walking tank or something. The people use bullets and airships. All I want to know is why. Have Charles Soule or some member of the Lucasfilm Story Group said anything regarding this and its story purpose?

Comment: Could you please expand your question.

Comment: If memory serves it had been colonised by accident and was otherwise uncontactable. That would explain the eclectic mix of technology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an interview on StarWars.com, the writer Charles Soule explained his approach towards the story. It does not give a direct answer to the question, but helps out in reasoning the background.

> *"They're going to meet up with a diplomatic fleet and then they hear a distress call from a planet that's supposed to be completely dead,
>   there's not supposed to be anything on it. So, they answer the
>   distress call and that's where the adventure begins."*

Like Obi-Wan told Anakin in the beginning of the story, the people of Carnelion IV destroyed themselves in a war generations ago. The genocide and hypothetical destruction of hi-tech blasters and vessels at same time justifies the existence of the backwater world. Firearms and airships seem to be a visualization of that to us readers.

Also, in order to keep the planet isolated and the destinies of its people unknown, they must not have anything hi-tech for interstellar communication or travel in large scale.

> *"That's how I broke into it, and then from there, it was fleshing out a world and a planet that hopefully would seem fresh, that we hadn't
>   seen before, and a type of Star Wars story that we hadn't seen
>   before."*

Soule wanted to create a unique world and probably thought a low-tech world would be more of the kind. Of course, there has been such planets in Star Wars media before, but they're still the minority.

> *"The series is set on a planet with mountain peaks over this huge rolling sea of green mist that obscures everything below because it's
>   a planet full of secrets. It gives you some opportunity to do some
>   really cool visuals with Jedi hopping around, using their lightsabers
>   in the snow, stuff like that."*

The comic book creators were after good-looking visuals. In order to justify such vessels as the Zeppelin-type airships, they thought they needed a low-tech world. And the airships did look pretty cool.

You can read the full interview [here](http://www.starwars.com/news/nycc-2015-exploring-the-uncharted-in-marvels-obi-wan-and-anakin-an-interview-with-charles-soule).